# Google Websearch through API

Tags: google-search-api

I'm trying to embed Google Search in one of our PHP apps. I'm using the endpoint:

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&api_key=MY_KEY&q=SEARCH_TERM`

I have registered the API key in the API console and granted access to my servers' IP address. Even with the use of API key, I'm getting the error:

`Quota Exceeded.  Please see http://code.google.com/apis/websearch`

The page says this API is deprecated but the page it redirects to is 404 and the one I can find about Custom Search only mentions searching within a set of sites. What I want to do instead is to perform normal Google search on all the web.

p.s. I am willing to pay for the service if Google has a paid service for this. I am just unable to find it. Am I completely missing the point or is there some small step I'm doing wrong. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API where you can replicate entirely generic Google search is deprecated and no longer offered. The closes product is Google Custom Search, where you can enable "search the entire web" option. This will search all web and not only selected sites, but will still be a Custom  Search, which means the results may differ from the generic google.com results.

Comment: Thanks for that. I finally figured that weird process out. The issue with that though is that even with billing enabled, you can get a maximum quota of 10k queries per day. And that at $5/1k queries. Not sure what they're playing at :(